# Audio Probe Cannot Set Source in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, audio, media-player

I am using a `QMediaPlayer` to play back an mp3 file, and I wish to set a `QAudioProbe` to monitor the output.  However, my call to `setSource()` always returns false in the following:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    x = new QVector<double>(256);
    y = new QVector<double>(256);
    values = new int[256];

    player = new QMediaPlayer();

    player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile(
                     "C:/Users/Person1/Desktop/piano.mp3"));
    player->setVolume(50);
    audioProbe = new QAudioProbe();

    if (audioProbe->setSource(player)) {
       connect(audioProbe, SIGNAL(audioBufferProbed(QAudioBuffer)),
               this, SLOT(updatePlot(QAudioBuffer)));
    }
    else {
        qDebug("source not set");
    }
}
```

Please note that `player` and `audioProbe` are initialized as pointers to `QMediaPlayer` and `QAudioProbe`, respectively, within the definition of the `MainWindow` class. The output always prints:

> source not set

But when I call `player->play()`, the file plays perfectly.  Is there something I am missing?  I have read the documentation quite thoroughly, and I could not find any problems with the method I employed.  I have also tried this with different mp3 files and a few wav files; they all play, but the same problem occurs when trying to set the source.

Comment: did you ever solve this? I am having the same issue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096322/generating-a-waveform-from-an-audio-or-video-file

Comment: I asked this question on the Qt forum, and the reply was that the Windows media player DirectX backend doesn't implement the QMediaAudioProbeControl; however the WMF backend does, and it therefore should work. I hope this helps.